# There are PostHistory records for deleted posts, but only a very few

Tags: bug, data-explorer, deleted-posts

Checking for the PostHistory entries in the SEDE for deleted Posts, I get some results, but only a very few.

For example, there is only 33 such records for the whole SO. All of them are from 2018.

I looked for them with [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/805905/all-posthistory-records-for-deleted-posts) query.

Is surely everything with your SEDE publisher script okay?

I am really hoping, you didn't forbid this very important feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there's nothing wrong, just a timing issue.

Take a look at the [timeline of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48722642/timeline). It has been deleted on February 10th, 16:04 and later, on February 11th, 5:19, it was undeleted. The last SEDE update, according to [the homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is February 11th, 7:22. What I expect to have happened is the following: when the `PostsWithDeleted` table was populated, the question was still deleted. It was not deleted anymore when the `PostHistory` table was populated.

Another example is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48727728/timeline).

In general, the PostHistory table **does not** include (and has never included) entries for deleted posts.

Comment: I am not sure you understood the question well. A little bit of inconsistency of the db could be explained if the SEDE upload doesn't happen in a single transaction, but it still leaves the question open, what is happened to the PostHistory records of the deleted posts.

Comment: @peterh they're not included in the dump.

Comment: Are you sure they never was? As I can remember, I could collect some stat including deleted posts, but I am not sure.

Comment: @peterh some information (like spam flags) *is* stored, e.g. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/646101/deleted-spam-offensive-posts

Comment: I know that, but this query is not coming from the PostHistory table. As I can remember, sometimes I could collect info for deleted posts from the PostHistory, but I am not sure.